# Java - PHP Number-Type Mix Up (9966006699)

Tags: java, php, types, numbers, primitive

I was doing some stuff with palindromes:

This number `9966006699` has been giving me problems. It's a product of `99979` and `99681`

```
99979 * 99681 = 9966006699
```

I ran that in `PHP`

```
$i = 99979 * 99681;
echo $i;
var_dump($i);
```

Outputs

```
9966006699 float(9966006699)
```

So in PHP the product is obviously a float data type. But in Java it's different as seen below :

This

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

      float f = 99979 * 99681;
       System.out.println(f);

       long o = 99979 * 99681;
       System.out.println(o);

       double d = 99979 * 99681;
       System.out.println(d);

       int i = 99979 * 99681;
       System.out.println(i);


   }
```

Outputs

```
1.37607206E9
1376072107
1.376072107E9
1376072107
```

Google's calculator gives the [right thing](http://www.google.com/search?gcx=c&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=99979%20%2a%2099681)

I'm lost, why is Java giving the wrong output? and Does it have anything to do with the `E9` stuff behind the float and double types? Help. Thanks

Comment: Java or PHP are not lying and lying is a rather unfitting word to describe what you see. Can you please elaborate what your problem is? Should make it easier to find an answer, which could be as trivial as using the right data-type.

Comment: Very peculiar, I can tell you the E9 means "times 10 to the power of 9), so it's essentially `1.37607206*10^9`. nothing to do with the miscalculation only accuracy thing.

Comment: @hakre What more detail can I give?

Comment: @Truth Ok. Thanks how do I solve this? Should I use `BigIntegers`?

Comment: `BigInteger` sounds promising even I don't know much about java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The numbers 99979 and 99681 are both int's.  The multiplication expression is therefore an int expression too.  The maximum value of an int expression is 2147......  Your value 9966006699 is way above that.  Hence you have fallen in the realms of the strange behaviour that you get from modulo-n arithmetic.  (That is, you have fallen victim to the C-family languages' version of the Y2K problem.)

Try this :

```
       long o = (long)99979 * 99681;
       System.out.println(o);
```

Comment: A certain guy named Mark Rotteveel has remarked that instead of the explicit cast (long)99979, you can also define a number to be of type long by writing 99979L.  Since I don't like the concept of changing anything to what others have said (nor of others changing what I have said), I'll leave my post as is and leave the credit for this correct remark where it is due (him iow).

Answer (score 2):

`Integer.MAX_VALUE` is equal to 2^31-1, which is smaller than the number you're dealing with, so you're essentially getting integer overflow issues.  You can get around this by using a `long`, or the [`BigInteger`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) class.

You can read about the numeric limits of primitive data types here:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Answer (score 2):

It looks like integer overflow as `9 966 006 699 > Integer.MAX_INT = 2 147 483 647`. As `int` times `int` have type `int` the result overflows. Then it is cast to int/float/long etc.

This should be correct (for non-int):

```
long value = (long)99979 * (long)99681
```

Alternativly you can use `BigInteger` class which:

1. May be slower the using `int`/`long`
2. Don't have this problem for any numbers (`long` just moves the problem from `2^31 - 1` to `2^63-1`).